# Max of independent and identical random variables is Markov

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains, conditional-probability

I'm supposed to show that given a sequence $\{Y_n\}$ of i.i.d the stochastic process
$$X_n=\max(Y_0, Y_1...,Y_n)$$
is a Markov of chain.

I think I could do it by induction but I would rather see how it is done by using principles of conditional probability as this would further my understanding more.

Any pointers or solutions are much appreciated.

Regards

ZMI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach: $X_0=Y_0$ and, for every $n$, $$X_{n+1}=A(X_n,Y_{n+1}),\qquad A(x,y)=\max\{x,y\}.$$ And now, watch the results fall in line like dominoes:

- Initial distribution: the distribution of $Y_0$
- Markov property: obvious since $X_{n+1}$ is a deterministic function of the present state $X_n$ and of a new input $Y_{n+1}$ which is independent of the past $(X_k)_{k\leqslant n}$ since the past $(X_k)_{k\leqslant n}$ depends on $(Y_k)_{k\leqslant n}$ only and $Y_{n+1}$ is independent of $(Y_k)_{k\leqslant n}$
- Transition probabilities: for every $y\gt x$, the transition $x\to y$ has probability $P(Y_{n+1}=y)=P(Y_0=y)$ and the only other transition with positive probability is the transition $x\to x$ with probability $P(Y_{n+1}\leqslant x)=P(Y_0\leqslant x)$